# Redirection in React Router Dom v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

What is the correct process for re-directions in v6? I was previously using the following code in v5, which was working fine:

```
<Route path="/login">
  {user ? <Redirect to="/" /> : <LoginStandard />}
</Route>
```

However, I would like to use the same logic in this version. When my user has logged in, I would like to redirect.

```
<Route path="/login">
  <Route index element={<LoginStandard />} />
</Route>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `Navigate` component to redirect. The conditional rendering logic still needs to be applied and components rendered out on the `Route` component's `element` prop.

Example:

```
<Route
  path="/login"
  element={user ? <Navigate to="/" replace /> : <LoginStandard />}
/>
```

It is often considered better practice to abstract this into a custom route protection component that conditionally renders an `Outlet` for nested routes or the `Navigate` component.

Example:

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const AnonymousRoute = ({ user }) => user
  ? <Navigate to="/" replace />
  : <Outlet />;
```

...

```
<Route element={<AnonymousRoute user={user} />}>
  <Route path="/login" element={<LoginStandard />} />
  ... other anonymous routes ...
</Route>
... other routes
```

Answer (score 1):

With React Router Dom `v6`, you redirect with [`Navigate`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/navigate) and [`useNavigate`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate) instead of [`Redirect`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect) and [`useHistory`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) used in `v5`. Something like below. See the comments:

```js
import { Navigate, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Foo() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  // Use navigate returned by useNavigate  when you are outside of JSX
  navigate("/");
  // Use Navigate the imported component when you are inside of JSX
  return <Route path="/login">{user ? <Navigate to="/" /> : <LoginStandard />}</Route>;
}
```